# Add custom DNS Server IP to an Azure VM NIC using ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I have tried to use the ARM template code below to create an Azure VM NIC and custom its DNS Server IP address. However, it appears, the ARM template is not working. Please what could be wrong.
this line  "dnsServers": "[[parameters('dnsAddress')]]" doesn't seem to work when the template is deployed and I get his error

```
"message": "Could not find member 'dnsSettings' on object of type 'NetworkInterfaceIpConfigurationProperties'. Path 'properties.ipConfigurations[0].properties.dnsSettings?
```

Has anyone else come across this issue?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
   
     "dnsAddress": {

      "type": "array",

      "metadata": {

        "Description": "The DNS address(es) of the DNS Server(s) used by the virtual network"

      },
      "defaultValue":["10.0.0.4"]

    },
     
   
  },
  "variables": {
    "nicName": "[concat(uniquestring(resourceGroup().id), 'myVMNic')]",
    "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/16",
    "subnetName": "Subnet",
    "subnetPrefix": "10.0.0.0/24",
    "virtualNetworkName": "MyVNET",
    "subnetRef": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', variables('virtualNetworkName'), variables('subnetName'))]"
   
  },
  "resources": [
    
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
      "name": "[variables('virtualNetworkName')]",
      "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "addressSpace": {
          "addressPrefixes": [
            "[variables('addressPrefix')]"
          ]
        },
        "subnets": [
          {
            "name": "[variables('subnetName')]",
            "properties": {
              "addressPrefix": "[variables('subnetPrefix')]"
            
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
      "name": "[variables('nicName')]",
      "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "ipconfig1",
            "properties": {
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
              },
              "dnsSettings": {
                  "dnsServers": "[[parameters('dnsAddress')]]"
                    
                }
              
            }
          }
        ]
      },
       "dependsOn": [
         "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', variables('virtualNetworkName'))]"
      ]
    }
    
    
  ]
 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [official ARM template reference of network interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/templates/microsoft.network/2020-05-01/networkinterfaces?tabs=json), `dnsSettings` is not a member of `ipConfigurations`, it's at the same level as `ipConfigurations` under `properties`:

[image]

So just try to move `dnsSettings` to the same level as `ipConfigurations` as below:

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
    "name": "[variables('nicName')]",
    "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [{
                "name": "ipconfig1",
                "properties": {
                    "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                    "subnet": {
                        "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "dnsSettings": {
            "dnsServers": "[[parameters('dnsAddress')]]"
        }
    },
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', variables('virtualNetworkName'))]"
    ]
}
```